# Refreshing section in table adds content instead of changing it

Tags: ariatemplates

I'm trying to use filtering to update a table's content. The data is displayed from the view, using foreach directives to build the table. Only displaying the table works as intended.

However, when I start filtering, the new data is added, without markup (`td`s and stuff are removed), in a `span` placed outside of the `table`. I have no idea why it's doing that.

I would like to know what I did wrong, and how I can get the expected result: update the table when I apply a filter on the view.

InstantAT reproducing the problem: http://juliandescottes.github.io/instantat/#5194e132e4b051dece0c7924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I should have specified the section type instead of wrapping it myself in `tbody`

This is the buggy section definition:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        {section { id : "table_data", macro: "tableContent"} /}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I replaced it by this definition:

```
<table>
    ...
    {section { id : "table_data", macro: "tableContent", type: "tbody"} /}
</table>
```

It attaches the section to the `tbody` itself, instead of a `span` which is the default container. Since `span` is not a valid child of `table` it was placed outside of it.

Demo: http://juliandescottes.github.io/instantat/#51961bcde4b0988ed5cb6869

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the span was rendered outside of the table is just related to the browser.
You basically can not put a span right here in the middle of a table, the browser will simply move it outside of the table. (Of course inside a cell -td- you can !)

So it's not related to the framework, and hence not an issue. It's just html and browsers.

Comment: You're right, it makes perfect sense. I'll leave the answer unchanged since it's the actual correction, and add in you explanation. Thanks!